# How to force linkage to non installed libraries during cross compilation

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker

My situation with `g++` is the following. I build a shared library called `libplugin.so`, which is loaded at run-time by an application. This `libplugin.so` links to some other shared libraries, with the `-no-as-needed` linker option, and to a static library.

Since `libplugin.so` itself does not use any of the symbols in the listed libraries, `-no-as-needed` is required to make the dynamic loader load all the required libraries - which are really referenced by the static library only - when the plugin is loaded at run-time. On my `x86` building machine, all the libraries listed as `-no-as-needed` are installed in the system. So, the library is built fine there and the program is also ok.

Now I am trying to cross compile for ARM, but there are some problems, because the linker cannot find the libraries  indicated as `-no-as-needed` in the system when building `libplugin.so`. The linked cannot find the libraries because they (deliberately) are not installed. I prefer not to install them.

So here is my question. As `libplugin.so` does not directly reference the libraries passed to `-no-as-needed` in any way, is there a way to "force" the linker to build `libplugin.so` although the ARM libraries passed to `-no-as-needed` do not exist in my x86 building system?

Below is an example:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -o libplugin.so module1.o module2.o -L./libstatic.a -Wl,--no-as-needed -lX11 -lXext -shared -s -fPIC
arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld: cannot find -lX11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik you can't easily do that. But since your library doesn't use anything in the shared libraries you want to link to , you should be able to trick the linker by creating a dummy libX11 library and link to that:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -x c -shared -o libX11.so -Wl,-soname,libX11.so.6 /dev/null
```

This will create a rather empty libX11.so that you can link to. The important part is the soname of this library, which must match the soname of the real library - you can figure that out with e.g.

```
readelf -a /lib/libX11.so |grep soname
```